# GAS UrlFetchApp, sending form data doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, fetch, disable

I'm trying to post a form data via UrlFetchApp to a website.
textbox is filled, but doesn't submit. maybe because of submit button has disabled property.
can I remove this property by fetch? or any solutions?

I tried delete disable property by VBAselenium, actually it works.

Driver.ExecuteScript "document.querySelector('#SubmitButton').removeAttribute('disabled');"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.